# orm Failed To Load When Doing sails lift

Tags: node.js, sails.js, node-modules

I'm using `"sails": "~0.12.1"`.  I'm connecting to a mysql db.  I can connect to the DB on MySQL Workbench, so the DB is working.  When I try to `sails lift` I get this error:

```
info: Starting app...

error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at /node_modules/include-all/index.js:129:29
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at requireAll (/node_modules/include-all/index.js:44:9)
    at buildDictionary (/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-build-dictionary/index.js:68:14)
    at Function.module.exports.optional (/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-build-dictionary/index.js:160:9)
    at Hook.loadModels (/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/moduleloader/index.js:344:23)
    at Hook.wrapper [as loadModels] (/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3095:19)
    at Array.async.auto.models (/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/orm/load-user-modules.js:20:23)
    at /node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:591:38
```

Update: config/connections.js

```
module.exports.connections = {
  mysql: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'quizzlydb'
  }
};
```

config/models.js

```
module.exports.models = {
  connection: 'mysql',
  migrate: 'alter'
};
```

package.json

```
...
"sails": "~0.12.1",
"sails-disk": "~0.10.9",
"sails-memory": "^0.10.6",
"sails-mysql": "^0.11.5",
"waterline": "^0.11.0",
...
```

Comment: There is probably a syntax error in either your connections or models configuration, or in one of your model definitions

Comment: You are right!  I was missing a comma in one of my models.  Thanks!

Comment: Thats why you always run linting tests :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was missing a comma inside one of my models.  Phew!  I thought I was going crazy for a second there.

Answer (score 0):

You can define those connections in the `config/env/development.js` or `config/env/test.js` or `config/env/production.js` files
so that they only spin up pools for the correct environments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning to code and started with Sails. So forgive me if my answer is not the best. I also had a problem when switching to MySQL but I then found out that I should have installed the MySQL adapter. After that it worked fine.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-mysql

And you also should place your connection details in /config/local.js (example code is given in /config/connections.js , you could place your connection details there but if you're using git or something like that you would like to use local.js as that file isn't uploaded so your credentials won't be published to an broad audience.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with sails version 0.12 and had nodejs version 14. Try to install nodejs version 12.19.1. no solutions helped, but it did.